# List blobs that do not belong to a folder in Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to list all the blobs (files, in my case) which are **not** stored in a particular folder, say `not-target` using the [official Python client library](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html).

I do know that the library function provides a `prefix` option in order to filter blobs by a desired path. However, I would like to do the opposite here - list only those blobs which do not exist in a provided path.

**Current solution**

- Iterate over all the blobs using `list_blobs`
- Filter out blobs by name which start with the blocklisted `not-target` path.

```py
for blob in bucket.list_blobs():
    if not blob.name.startswith('not-target/'):
        # process the blob
```

**Shortcomings**

- Takes a lot of time because most of the blobs in the bucket belong to this folder.

Is there an optimization for this task that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach can be done with the `prefix` and `delimiter` arguments for the [`list_blobs`](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/buckets.html) method.

For example, if you want to list all the objects that are in `root` but not inside a folder, you can use the following code snippet:

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket("my_bucket")
all_blobs = list(client.list_blobs(bucket, prefix="", delimiter="/"))

for blob in all_blobs:
    print (blob.name)
```

Also, note that when listing in `root` it is not necessary to add the `prefix` argument:

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket("my_bucket")
all_blobs = list(client.list_blobs(bucket, delimiter="/"))

for blob in all_blobs:
    print (blob.name)
```

Another approach could be for example, to list the files inside a folder but not recursively, i.e. the objects in the root of that folder. Then the code could be:

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket("my_bucket")
all_blobs = list(client.list_blobs(bucket,prefix="folder/", delimiter="/"))

for blob in all_blobs:
    print (blob.name)
```

You can change the `prefix` depending on the path to use when listing.

In case you may want to list everything except a particular folder, there is no direct way to do it using the Cloud Storage libs. In this case, I think the best approach will be filtering the data at client side. You can use a regular expression to filter the list that you got after listing in Storage:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import re
regex = re.compile(r'folder.*')

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket("my_bucket")
all_blobs = list(client.list_blobs(bucket))

filtered = [blob for blob in all_blobs if not regex.match(blob.name)]

for blob in filtered:
    print(blob.name)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. The `delimiter` works for listing down blobs in a directory. How should it be modified to recursively list blobs within folders  (non-target) present in the root of the bucket as well?

Comment: I don't get at all to what you refer to "non-target". Anyway I've edited my answer. I've included a sample when you want to list everything except a folder.

Answer (score 0):

To restate the OP's question, we have a top-level folder `"not-target/"`, which has many files in it, meaning that iterating through them is prohibitively inefficient. We want to list all other blobs, however, including those at the top level (aka root folder) and those in any subfolder (recursively) that doesn't start with `"not-target/"`.

To do this we are going to do three things:

1. Get blobs in the root (top) level - these are not in any folder, hence are in scope for being not in `"not-target"`.
2. Get folders at the root level, ignoring folder `"not-target"`.
3. For each of these folders, get all (recursively) contained blobs.
4. Print out the all the blob names (i.e. paths).

Code:

```
import google.cloud.storage as gcs
BUCKET_NAME = "my-cloud-bucket" # The name for bucket gs://my-cloud-bucket
skip_folders = {"not-target/"} # Folders need to have trailing slash "/"
client = gcs.Client()
root_iter = client.list_blobs(
    bucket_or_name=BUCKET_NAME,
    delimiter="/",
)
root_blobs = list(root_iter)
root_folders = root_iter.prefixes
sub_blobs = []
for folder in root_folders:
    if folder in skip_folders:
        continue
    sub_blobs += list(client.list_blobs(
        bucket_or_name=BUCKET_NAME,
        prefix=folder
    ))
for blob in root_blobs + sub_blobs:
    print(blob.name)
```

Some notes to consider:

1. Since we are working at the root level, we don't need to specify kwarg `prefix=""`, but you could.
2. For `root_iter`, we **only** want blobs at this level, so specify kwarg `delimiter="/"`.
3. You need to iterate through `root_iter` before accessing `root_iter.prefixes`. This object is lazy loaded, meaning this member won't be populated before the object makes the api call, and to do that you need you need to get at least the first element. We want all the elements (root level blobs) so `list(root_iter)` does this for us.
4. `root_iter.prefixes` gets the folders at the root level for us - with trailing slashes `".../"`.
5. For `sub_blobs`, we want all blobs in all subfolder recursively, so in this case we do not give the `delimiter` kwarg.