# How to list all the blob files that don't belong to any subfolders in Azure Storage explorer using python

Tags: python, list, containers, azure-blob-storage, blob

I want to list down all the blob files that don't belong to any subfolders inside a blob container in Azure Storage Explorer. I'm using **python**.

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62997882/list-blobs-that-do-not-belong-to-a-folder-in-cloud-storage) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70680178/list-only-blobs-files-in-a-container-and-not-directories-sub-directories-sub-f) and tested it.But I'm getting an error.

This is my code.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

def main(inputblob: func.InputStream, outputblob: func.Out[bytes]):
connection_string = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;'
container_name="cloudops-resources"


#create the BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
#list blobs 
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_list = container_client.list_blobs(container_name, prefix="", delimiter="/")
blobs = []
for blob in blob_list:
    print(blob.name)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.BlobTrigger. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
> Exception: TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'delimiter'

This was the only method I can found.Can someone please help me?

Comment: walk blob has a parameter delimiter. I don't think list_blob has, so remove delimiter = '/'

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list-python

Comment: Then it's not listing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

Initially, I had some blobs and folders in my storage account.

**Portal:**

[image]

> I want to list down all the blob files that don't belong to any subfolders inside a blob container in Azure Storage Explorer

You can use the below code to get the list of blobs that does not belongs to any folders.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

connection_string = ""
container_name = "test2"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()

for blob in blob_list:
    if "/" not in blob.name:
        print(blob.name)
```

**Output:**

The above code was executed and successfully listed blobs.

```
27-03-2023.html
28-03-2023.html
29-03-2023 (1).html
29-03-2023 (2).html
29-03-2023.html
30-03-2023.html
31-03-2023 (1).html
31-03-2023 (2).html
```

[image]

**Reference:**
[List blobs with Python - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list-python)